# Nested vlookup in Excel? - Getting a specific number in an array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I will give an example of what I need to accomplish.

Suppose I have the following table

[image]

This table contains the Salesman ID and the Product ID that he/she sells.

I have a different database that needs to relate the amount of product any salesman sells.

That being said, suppose I need to know how many Product ID 13 did salesman ID 3 sold: that is 15.

I tried doing a combination of IF + VLOOKUP but it doesn't drill down to needed information (Vlookup will stop when it finds desired Salesman ID and will not return the desired Product ID)

Desired output should take a Salesman ID and a Product ID and return a Number of Sales of Product

I would really appreciate if someone can give me light on this.
Thanks

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JBuf.png is the link for the example of the table. Thanks

Comment: use a pivot table with filters

Comment: If you want a formula then look into SUMIFS